# Where can I find a driver for an Epson XP-405 printer?

Tags: software-installation

Is there a driver for an Epson XP-405 printer?

I asked Epson but they could not help.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2091976) thread on the Ubuntu Forums, the correct driver is available here: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=18786&DSCCHK=9b896a8ce134b9e9ed63ba6bf8190361ee56e412